# Cannot create nested documents in Moqui for Elasticsearch

Tags: moqui

I am not able to explicitly map a particular filed according to my specific requirements.
For example if I take the WorkEffort data model used in HiveMind, then while creating the schema to Index tasks, I cannot specify which type mapping I want to do regarding a specific field.

If I want to nest the details of the Milestones and People associated with a particular task and then query them according to the above values, then I am not able to achieve that.

For example if I want to fetch the results based on the Assignee or the Milestone, I will not be able to achieve that.

So is there any way where I can specify the type of mapping respective to that field, while creating the Document Data for defining a schema according to my choice?

This will allow me to specify which fields are nested and query them accordingly.

Comment: This question is unclear: What do you mean by "nested documents"? How is what you're looking for different from what is already in the HiveMind task documents? You can see both milestones and parties associated with a task by going to http://demo.moqui.org/apps/system/DataDocument/Search then searching for "004" and click on "View Document" for the HM-004 task.

Comment: This link would better state for what I meant https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-nested-type.html

Comment: The simple answer is no, nested instead of object types are not used for the ElasticSearch document definitions generated by Moqui. Perhaps this question could be rephrased in terms of what you are trying to accomplish.